# Assigning value to LPVOID

Tags: c++

im following a game making tutorial on the web,
and the guy the proceeds to assign an LPVOID like this

```
LPVOID BaseAddress = (LPVOID)2199023255552;
```

but when i try to do the same it always ends up being 0.
could anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: That tutorial is probably outdated by years. Hardcoding any memory addresses in userspace applications is not useful nowadays. Please provide a link to that tutorial, too.

Comment: The tutorial assumes that you're building for a 64-bit system. That number doesn't fit in a 32-bit pointer. Judging by the code in question, you should switch tutorials. Or better yet, buy a book.

Comment: Could you provide a full listing of your code to see how do you know that the value is 0? Do you debug your code or `printf("%p")` ?

Comment: thanks for response. here is the tutorial link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcENxzeTjbI#t=3230. and no its a new tutorial. it shows up as 0 when im stepping through it in VS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the bad idea of randomly assigning an integer and trying use that value a LPVOID, what it is probably happening is:

- Either, you are not compiling to a 64-bit system (as molbdnilo mentioned it in a comment) and therefore assigning a value greater than 32-bit to a 32-bit variable triggers an undefined behavior in the compiler. Try using a smaller value like 20, and see if the variable is still 0. Basically in these cases the compiler can do whatever it wants even assigning it to 0xDEADBEEF if it wants to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior
- Or, you are not using the variable, and therefore the compiler is optimizing it out (the rationale would be: why would the computer loose time assigning a value to a memory location if you are not going to use it?)

Comment: as you guys said. the problem was using a 32-bit compiler.